# Reflection - How to copy common properties from one class to another when there are subclasses

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm working on a c# application and trying to make this code working. It fails when it tries to copy a property which is a list of a subclass object.
I'm able to check the common properties in both classes and the code works fine for most types I've used, even `List<string>`. When I have properties of type e.g. `List<SubClass>`it fails. The code fails also for simple objects of the Subclass.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Questions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1
            {
                Prop1 = "X",
                List1 = new List<Class1.SubClass>
                {
                    new Class1.SubClass { SubProp1 = "A", SubProp2 = "B" }
                }
            };

            Class2 class2 = class1.CopyTo<Class2>();    //---> fails when it tries to SetValue for the List<SubClass>
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public List<SubClass> List1 { get; set; }

        public string Prop3 { get; set; }

        public class SubClass
        {
            public string SubProp1 { get; set; }
            public string SubProp2 { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public List<SubClass> List1 { get; set; }

        public string Prop4 { get; set; }

        public class SubClass
        {
            public string SubProp1 { get; set; }
            public string SubProp2 { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T CopyTo<T>(this Object sourceObject) 
        {
            Type sourceObjectType = sourceObject.GetType();
            Type targetType = typeof(T);
            var targetInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType, false);

            List<PropertyInfo> identicalProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

            var propertiesTarget = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            var propertiesSource = sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var s_property in propertiesSource)
            {
                foreach (var t_property in propertiesTarget)
                {
                    if (s_property.Name.Equals(t_property.Name))
                    {
                        identicalProperties.Add(s_property);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            object value;

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertiesTarget)
            {
                var res = identicalProperties.Any(x=>x.Name.Equals(property.Name));
                if (!res)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                value = sourceObjectType.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(sourceObject, null);
                property.SetValue(targetInstance, value, null);
            }

            return (T)targetInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

I assume this is achievable but I'm struggling to find a way to identify the type of property and when to cast the `value` to the correct type here `property.SetValue(targetInstance, value, null);`. `value` should probably be casted as a `List`.

The error thrown by the compiler is:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Questions.Class1+SubClass]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Questions.Class2+SubClass]'

Can anyone help?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use something like AutoMapper or similar, which will be faster and has been tested by millions people?

Comment: A `List<Derived>` is **not** a `List<Base>` and that's your problem. Classes are not variant that way (interfaces can be). You'd need to (for example) create a `List<Base>` and then add items of type `Derived` to it manually

Comment: @ptuga: if you are wondering why a `List<Derived>` is not a `List<Base>` consider having a `List<Dog>` and passing it to a function that considers it a `List<Animal>`. That function could include the List code `listOfAnimals.Add(new Cat())`. That would be bad

Comment: @00110001 _"Why not just use... [xyz]"_ - perhaps but I can't help but feel that responses like that aren't particularly helpful because **1)** the OP may not learn anything in the process and **2)** prevents the creation of future and possibly improved _open-source_ projects.   I would hate to live in a universe where _Serilog_ was never invented because people were repeatedly told to use log4net.  **3)** AutoMapper adds to application start-up time; isn't particularly _"automatic"_ and in any reasonably complex project requires quite alot of manual configuration

Comment: Your problem is that you aren't checking for type-compatibility and are only checking for name equality. Try having a `int` in `Class1` and a `long` in `Class2`. Boom. Unless you can be very very sure your problem is restricted to the example given, any work done to solve this single problem is wasted time. Remapping data is a complex argument The named Automapper class (that is everything but automatic) is a truly big piece of code, and it shows how much complex the problem is.

Comment: @Flydog57: Thanks for your comments. Not sure thought how to can I use a `List<Base>` for my specific example. I have moved the `SubClass` definition outside my classes `Class1` and `Class2` and the code runs fine now. Is this in line with your suggestion? Please clarify.

Comment: @xanatos: In this specific example, I'm expecting the types to always be the same. But the idea would be to verify the `Type` using `Reflection` before the copy to be able to cast it to that `Type` (if that was even possible). In any case, moving the definition of the `SubClass` outside my classes is suitable for me and if it is less probable to work in any other way, I'm fine with that. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of further details or comments I would just like to feedback the final solution I'm adopting. Basically, the use of a outside defined class (instead an internal defined class) will allow the code to work but and provides a practical example how it can work based on this assumption. This is an workaround rather than the solution for my original question.
The example final code as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Questions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1
            {
                Prop1 = "X",
                Prop2 = "Y",
                List1 = new List<OutsideClass>
                {
                    new OutsideClass { SubProp1 = "A", SubProp2 = "B" },
                    new OutsideClass { SubProp1 = "C", SubProp2 = "D" },
                    new OutsideClass { SubProp1 = "E", SubProp2 = "F" }
                }
            };

            Class2 class2 = class1.CopyTo<Class2>();

        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public List<OutsideClass> List1 { get; set; }

        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    }


    public class Class2
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public List<OutsideClass> List1 { get; set; }

        public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class OutsideClass
    {
        public string SubProp1 { get; set; }
        public string SubProp2 { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string text = string.Format("{0} ---> {1}", SubProp1, SubProp2);
            return text;
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T CopyTo<T>(this Object sourceObject) 
        {
            Type sourceObjectType = sourceObject.GetType();
            Type targetType = typeof(T);
            var targetInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType, false);

            List<PropertyInfo> identicalProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

            var propertiesTarget = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            var propertiesSource = sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var s_property in propertiesSource)
            {
                foreach (var t_property in propertiesTarget)
                {
                    if (s_property.Name.Equals(t_property.Name))
                    {
                        identicalProperties.Add(s_property);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            object value;

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertiesTarget)
            {
                var res = identicalProperties.Any(x=>x.Name.Equals(property.Name));
                if (!res)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                value = sourceObjectType.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(sourceObject, null);
                property.SetValue(targetInstance, value, null);
            }

            return (T)targetInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

All common properties will be copied from one class to the other (`Prop3` and `Prop4` will be disregarded as they only exist in each one of these classes).
I hope this can help anyone trying to do the same.
Please feel free to comment back and provide further details.

Thanks a lot for everyone comments.

Happy new year!